# DroneKit simple takeoff not working

Tags: dronekit, dronekit-android, 3dr

I'm trying to make a simple `Takeoff` command.

Here is the code below:

```
ControlApi.getApi(this.drone).takeoff(10, new AbstractCommandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int executionError) {
                alertUser("Error: " + executionError);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTimeout() {

                alertUser("timeout");

            }
        });
```

Although I am managing to ARM the copter, the takeoff command always returns error, with `executionError` 3 or 4
and I don't know what it means?
Any one have the `executionError` codes meanings?
Or maybe know what is the issue?

Comment: You need to arm the copter, and you also need to be in guided mode. Have you met both of those conditions?

Comment: @squilter Yes, first I'm arming, then switching to guided mode with `VehicleApi.getApi(this.drone).setVehicleMode(VehicleMode.COPTER_GUIDED);` and then the code above.

Comment: Did you wait to get confirmation that the mode change was successful?

Comment: @squilter yes, I am waiting until `AttributeEvent.STATE_VEHICLE_MODE` in the `onDroneEvent` changed, and then pushing the takeoff button.
Any other thoughts?
BTW did you manage to takeoff with real quad copter?
I'm asking because for testing I'm using real quad copter with PX4 controller.

Comment: Oh, dronekit-android is really only designed to work with ArduCopter. It could definitely be made to work with PX4, but I wouldn't expect it to work out of the box.

Comment: @squilter I have another question about droneKit , can you please have a look at it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43832575/dronekit-mission-not-sent-to-drone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Solved]**.
Here is the steps that need to be taken in order the code to work:

**1.**

```
VehicleApi.getApi(this.drone).arm(true, new AbstractCommandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int executionError) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTimeout() {

            }
        });
```

Make sure you get proper response in `onSuccess` method.

**2.**

```
VehicleApi.getApi(drone).setVehicleMode(VehicleMode.COPTER_GUIDED);
```

Here is where was my problem. I somehow managed to put the copter in [`Guided_NoGps`](http://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/ac2_guidedmode.html#guided-nogps) 
According to Arducopter documentation, this mode can be put without sufficient GPS satellites count.
Also you need a 3DFix in GPS to switch to `Guided` Mode.
You need to make sure you have more than 9 stable satellites locks or this code just wont work.

**3.**

Run the code below

```
ControlApi.getApi(this.drone).takeoff(10, new AbstractCommandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int executionError) {
                alertUser("Error: " + executionError);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTimeout() {

                alertUser("timeout");

            }
        });
```

I have tested this on real quad-copter based on PX4 controller. 
Also you need ArduCopter version 3.4 (or above)