# DroneKit mission not sent to drone

Tags: dronekit, dronekit-android, 3dr

I'm trying to create simple mission using Drone-Kit android.

```
Mission myMission = new Mission();
myMission.clear();
Takeoff to = new Takeoff();
ReturnToLaunch rtl = new ReturnToLaunch();
//set Altitude in meters
rtl.setReturnAltitude(2);
to.setTakeoffAltitude(2);
myMission.addMissionItem(to);
myMission.addMissionItem(rtl);
MissionApi.getApi(this.drone).setMission(myMission,true);
```

The problem is that sometimes it works, and sometimes it's doesn't...
I don't know why it not working... I'm not getting any errors in the code.

I'm listening to the

```
AttributeEvent.MISSION_UPDATED

AttributeEvent.MISSION_SENT

AttributeEvent.MISSION_RECEIVED
```

but only the `AttributeEvent.MISSION_UPDATED` is fired when I run the code.
And even if its fired, this doesn't mean that the mission updated correctly.
I'm checking the mission with Mission Planer.
I just don't understand why it is working sometimes and sometimes not.

I did make sure that the drone connected to the app.
Also I made sure that the drone is OK and arm-able.
I really stuck here... and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my question, in case someone have the same problem.

I have contacted the developers, and it seems that I'm not the only one who have this BUG.
It seems that when you add `ReturnToLaunch` to `Mission` something happening in the API and the mission is not sent to the drone. As soon as I removed `ReturnToLaunch` object from the `Mission` all worked properly.

**Work-Around**: To overcome the issue, I am putting the drone in `RTL` mode, when the `Mission` is done.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried dronekit-android before but I think it is better to open an issue [here](https://github.com/dronekit/dronekit-android).

The source code for android project has not been updated for more than two years!

In general,there is a protocol to upload/download a mission. It is not easy to implement but you can implement it. I did that in c++. You should always check the acknowledgment from the drone before going in the next step. Check the protocol [here](http://qgroundcontrol.org/mavlink/waypoint_protocol).